# DBlink error when querying the remote table

Tags: oracle, dblink, tns

I am creating DB link by using below command. I have not updated tnsnames.ora instead I used details in the commmand.

```
  CREATE DATABASE LINK test
  CONNECT TO apps IDENTIFIED BY xyzabc
  USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=awsss3270429.us.dell.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dell122de))';
```

The `DBLink` was created successfully. but

When I fired below query I got the error.

```
select * from USER_CS_SRS@test; . table `USER_CS_SRS` exist in remote database.
```

Error is attached.[image]

I am quite new to DB. Can anybody help me on the same.

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` in the connect string - should end `..=opm122de)))';`. If you recreate the link with that, does it then work?

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole . it did not work. Can there be some tns related error?

Comment: It gave the same ORA-12154, or changed to something else like ORA-12545?

Comment: I did not change anything @AlexPoole . it is screenshot of error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - how do you know it didn't work if you didn't try? Drop the DB link, create it again with the extra `)`, and run your query again. What ORA- error does that then give you?

Comment: @AlexPoole  I got another error when I am creating DBlink in Dbaas. Could you please help me on this?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327074/db-link-not-working-in-dbaas-but-working-in-on-premise-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of your connection string. Your create statement should end:

```
...(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=opm122de)))';
-----------------------------------------^
```

Recreating what you posted:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK test
CONNECT TO apps IDENTIFIED BY xyzabc
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=rws3270429.us.oracle.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=opm122de))';

select * from USER_CS_SRS@test;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
...
```

Adding the final `)` changes that:

```
drop database link test;

CREATE DATABASE LINK test
CONNECT TO apps IDENTIFIED BY xyzabc
USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=rws3270429.us.oracle.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=opm122de)))';

select * from USER_CS_SRS@test;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
...
```

which is a different error; for me that's entirely reasonable because I can't resolve `rws3270429.us.oracle.com`, never mind reach it. As your profile says you work for Oracle, presumably you can - and this either works or throws a different error. Either way the original ORA-12154 error has been fixed.

Comment: thank you so much Alex. you were right. I missed that bracket. I apologies for wasting your time and thank you so much for your kind help.