# DB link not working in DBaaS but working in On premise Database

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dblink, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using below command to create `DB link`

```
CREATE  DATABASE LINK Dblink_test2
  CONNECT TO apps IDENTIFIED BY xyzabc
  USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=awss007.us.dell.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxmm122de)))';
```

The DB link got created successfully and it is returning data when I am creating it in on premise database.

But when I am doing same in my `Dbaas` ,`DB link` is getting created but when I am running query I am getting below error.

```
select * from emp@Dblink_test2;
```

[image]

`table` is there. Same is working when I am creating `DB link` in `on premise database`.

Issue is coming when local environment is `DBaas` and Remote is `On premise Database`.

Could you please help me on the same?

Comment: As I said in a previous answer, either you can't resolve `awss007.us.oracle.com` to an IP address or you can't reach that IP address, from the DB server.

Comment: That worked Alex. This IP is for remote DB. when I am creating DB link in my another on premise DB the same remote is working fine. Now my local environment is DBaaS But remote is same. That address is working fine when local is on premise.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole . I focused on your suggestion and replaced hostname by IP address and that worked fine. thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `hostname` by `IP address` and it worked successfully.

```
CREATE  DATABASE LINK Dblink_test2
  CONNECT TO apps IDENTIFIED BY xyzabc
  USING '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.32.33.22)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oam122de)))';
```

The above one is working fine.

Comment: Which would indicate that you don't have your DNS server configured to know about the awss server.

Comment: Thanks @EdStevens I will check the same.